# Constant terms in ring equations

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n$ be a natural number and $a,b \in R$. If $R$ is a ring, does $na = nb \Longrightarrow a = b$? What important rings satisfy this requirement?

Oh I think integers mod a composite number is a counterexample. What are others?

Comment: Rings of [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)) zero. Then $nc=0$ implies $c=0$ (let $c=a-b$).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that $na$ has the classical meaning (  $a+a+a+\cdots+a$ if $n\geq 0$ and $-a+\cdots+-a$ otherwise)

Your answer to your first question is NO. Take $R=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as a counterexample.

In fact, if you quantify properly your question, that is if you ask that for all $a,b\in R$, $na=nb\Rightarrow a=b$, then the rings satisfying this property are exactly those which have characteristic prime to $n$. You have a lot of rings with characteristic prime to $n$ : $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ with $m$ prime to $n$, $R[X]$ where $R$ has characteristic prime to $n$...

**Remainder:** the characteristic of a ring $R$ is the smallest positive integer $c$ such that $c1_R=0_R$ if such integer exists, and $0$ otherwise.